# Finding insertion points in a sorted array faster than O(n)?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, insert

This is for game programming. Lets say I have a Unit that can track 10 enemies within it's range. Each enemy has a priority between 0-100. So the array currently looks like this (numbers represent priority):

```
Enemy - 96
Enemy - 78
Enemy - 77
Enemy - 73
Enemy - 61
Enemy - 49
Enemy - 42
Enemy - 36
Enemy - 22
Enemy - 17
```

Say a new enemy wanders within range and has a priority of `69`, this will be inserted between `73` and `61`, and `17` will be removed from the array (Well, the 17 would be removed before the insertion, I believe).

Is there any way to figure out that it needs to be inserted between `73` and `61` without an O(n) operation?

Comment: O(log2(n)) i.e.: try to insert in the middle

Comment: look up binary search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel you're asking the wrong question here. You have to both first find the spot to insert into and then insert the element. These are two operation that are both tied together and I feel you shouldn't be asking about how to find where to do one faster without the other. It'll make sense why towards the end of the question. But I'm addressing the question of actually inserting faster.

**Short Answer:** No

**Answer you'll get from someone that's too smart for themselves:**

The only way to accomplish this is to not use an array. In an array unless you are inserting into the first or last permissions the insert will be O(n). This is because the array consists of its elements occupying contiguous space in memory. That is how you are able to reference a particular element in O(1) time, you know exactly where that element is. The cost is to insert in the middle you need to move half the elements in the array. So while you can look up with a binary search in log(n) time you cannot insert in that time.

So if you're going to do anything, you'll need a different data structure. A simple binary tree may be the solution it will do the insertion in log(n) time. On the other hand if you're feeding it a sorted array you have to worry about tree balancing, so not you might need a red and black tree. Or if you are always popping the element that is the closest or the furthest then you can use heap sort. A heap sort is the best algorithm for a priority queue. It has an additional advantage of fitting a tree structure in an array so it has far better spatial locality (more on this later).

**The truth:**

You'll most likely have a dozen maybe a few dozen enemies in the vicinity at most. At that level the asymptotic performance does not matter because it is designed especially for large values of 'n'. What you're looking at is a religious adherence to your CS 201 professor's calls about Big Oh. Linear search and insertion will be the fastest method, and the answer to will it scale is, who the hell cares. If you try to implement a complicated algorithm to scale it, you will almost always be slower since what is determining your speed is not the software, it is the hardware, and you're better off sticking to doing things that the hardware knows how to deal with well: "linearly going down memory". In fact after the prefetchers do their thing it would be faster to linearly go through each element even if there were a couple of thousand elements than to implement a red and black tree. Because a data structure like a tree would allocate memory all over the place without any regard to spatial locality. And the calls to allocate more memory for a node are in themselves more expensive than the time it takes to read through a thousand elements. Which is why graphics cards use insert sort all over the place.

**Heap Sort**

Heap sort might actually be faster depending on the input data since it is using a linear array although it may confuse the prefetchers so it's hard to say. The only limitation is that you can only pop the highest priority element. Obviously you can define highest priority to be either the lowest or the largest element. Heap sort is too fancy for me to try and describe it over here, just Google it. It does separate insertion and removal into two O(log(n)) operations. The biggest downside of heap sort is it will seriously decrease the debugability of the code. A heap is not a sorted array, it has an order to it, but other than heap sort being a complicated unintuitive algorithm, it is not apparently visible to a human being if a heap is setup correctly. So you would introduce more bugs for in the best case little benefit. Hell, the last time I had to do a heap sort I copied the code for it and that had bugs in it.

**Insertion Sort With Binary Search**

So this is what it seems like you're trying to do. The truth is this is a very bad idea. On average insertion sort takes O(n). And we know this is a hard limit for inserting a random element into a sorted array. Yes we can find the element we want to insert into faster by using a binary search. But then the average insertion still takes O(n). Alternatively, in the best case, if you are inserting and the element goes into the last position insertion sort takes O(1) time because when you inserted, it is already in the correct place. However, if you do a binary search to find the insertion location, then finding out you're supposed to insert in the last position takes O(log(n)) time. And the insertion itself takes O(1) time. So in trying to optimize it, you've severely degraded the best case performance. Looking at your use case, this queue holds the enemies with their priorities. The priority of an enemy is likely a function of their strength and their distance. Which means when an enemy enters into the priority queue, it will likely have a very low priority. This plays very well into the best case of insertion of O(1) performance. If you decrease the best case performance you will do more harm than good because it is also your most general case.

> Preoptimization is the root of all evil -- Donald Knuth

Comment: Good answer although he does only specify that he needs to *find* the insertion point better than O(n)

Comment: Thank you @ClintGood. I added some explanation for why you need to be looking at the search and insertion operations in tandem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are maintaining a sorted search pool at all times, you can use binary search. First check the middle element, then check the element halfway between the middle element and whichever end of the array is closer, and so on until you find the location. This will give you O(log<sub>2</sub>*n*) time.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, assuming you are using an Array type to house the list this really easy.

I will assume `Enemy` is your class name, and that is has a property called `Priority` to perform the sort.  We will need an `IComparer<Enemy>` that looks like the following:

```
public class EnemyComparer : IComparer<Enemy>
{
    int IComparer<Enemy>.Compare(Enemy x, Enemy y)
    {
        return y.Priority.CompareTo(x.Priority); // reverse operand to invert ordering
    }
}
```

Then we can write a simple `InsertEnemy` routine as follows:

```
public static bool InsertEnemy(Enemy[] enemies, Enemy newEnemy)
{
    // binary search in O(logN)
    var ix = Array.BinarySearch(enemies, newEnemy, new EnemyComparer());
    // If not found, the bit-wise compliment is the insertion index
    if (ix < 0)
        ix = ~ix;
    // If the insertion index is after the list we bail out...
    if (ix >= enemies.Length)
        return false;// Insert is after last item...
    //Move enemies down the list to make room for the insertion...
    if (ix + 1 < enemies.Length)
        Array.ConstrainedCopy(enemies, ix, enemies, ix + 1, enemies.Length - (ix + 1));
    //Now insert the newEnemy into the position
    enemies[ix] = newEnemy;
    return true;
}
```

There are other data structures that would make this a bit faster, but this should prove efficient enough.  A B-Tree or binary tree would be ok if the list will get large, but for 10 items it's doubtful it would be faster.

The method above was tested with the addition of the following:

```
public class Enemy
{
    public int Priority;
}

public static void Main()
{
    var rand = new Random();
    // Start with a sorted list of 10
    var enemies = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new Enemy() {Priority = rand.Next(0, 100)}).OrderBy(e => e.Priority).ToArray();
    // Insert random entries
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        InsertEnemy(enemies, new Enemy() {Priority = rand.Next(100)});
}
```

Comment: A B-tree is not a binary tree: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree . It is a data structure used in designing databases. A single-node in a B-tree holds a sorted array of of elements and pointers, sized so that the the node occupies close to one disk block of memory. You should edit where you said B-tree.

Comment: @ali-hussain  I know, that was why I said "b-tree OR binary tree" and a b-tree can have an order of 2, making it viable for this solution.